# Turn python list into lowercase

Tags: python

I tried every method I could find online but non of them worked. Can someone help me to turn everything in *lista* lowercase. I try to find duplicates in it but it doesn't count a lowercase and an uppercase character as duplicate.

```
from sys import stdin, stdout

def main():
    n = int(stdin.readline())
    iso = 0
    if n <= 0:
        print("Nope")
    else:
        lista = []
        m = n
        while m != 0:
            lista.append(stdin.readline())
            m -= 1
        l = 0
        
        while l < n:
            lst = list(lista[l])
            bol = False
            if " " in lst:
                lst.remove(" ")
            if "\n" in lst:
                lst.remove("\n")
            for i in lst:
                if lst.count(i) < 3:
                    bol = True
            if bol == True:
                iso += 1
            l += 1

    stdout.write(str(iso))

main()
```

Comment: It's not clear what your code is doing at all; your variable names are cryptic and there's zero explanation of anything. In order for a human to follow your code it's much harder than it has to be. And it's not obvious what you're doing to try to make things lowercase. You're not using the `str` `lower()` method anywhere. If you have a variable `var` whose value is `"STRING"`, if you do `print(var.lower())` for instance, it'll print `string`. The `lower()` method returns a lowercase version of the string. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

Comment: My variable names are cryptic because i'm from Hungary, and they are referring to hungarian words. If i try to use `str` it gives me an error. But my problem is solved now.

Comment: Even if they're not English words, having variable names that are a single letter is usually discouraged. And when posting here, an English site, your [mre] should be understandable in English. Also I never said to literally use `str` anywhere, I meant that strings have a `lower()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading in the inputs you can do:

```
while m != 0:
    read_in_string = stdin.readline()
    lista.append(read_in_string.lower())
    m -= 1
```

To make the things in lista lower case